# How to rotate player & camera (unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

im making a gravity thing so when you right click it should make the character and camera rotate but im not really sure how to make the camera rotate. this is the code i have for the gravity.

```
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) && grounded)
    {
        Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, 10.0f, 0);

    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && grounded)
    {
        Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, -10.0f, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Transform cam;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) && grounded)
    {
        Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, 10.0f, 0);
        cam.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 180f);

    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && grounded)
    {
        Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, -10.0f, 0);
        cam.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f);
    }

}
```

Comment: it didnt work, i assigned the camera and everything,

Comment: What does the code look like now?

Comment: How do you want the camera to rotate? Do you want the camera to just rotate when right click or do you want the camera to always look at the character or do you want the camera to rotate 180 degrees?

Comment: the code is if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse1) && grounded)
        {
            Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, 10.0f, 0);
            cam.Rotate(0f, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, Space.World);

        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && grounded)
        {
            Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, -10.0f, 0);
            cam.Rotate(0f, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, Space.World);
        }

Comment: i just realized i messed up the code and realized that is does work, but i would like the code to make it so its not when the mouse is held down but it flips when it clicks, and i would like it to flip upside down

Comment: If you wanted to smoothly rotate you could use animations.